# C++ Instantiating "Implicit" Class Object

Tags: c++, object, constructor, instantiation, objectinstantiation

```
class Cents
{
private:
int m_nCents;

public:
Cents(int nCents) { m_nCents = nCents; }

// Overload cCents + int
friend Cents operator+(const Cents &cCents, int nCents);
int GetCents() { return m_nCents; }
};

// note: this function is not a member function!
Cents operator+(const Cents &cCents, int nCents)
{
return Cents(cCents.m_nCents + nCents);
}

int main()
{
Cents c1 = Cents(4) + 6;
std::cout << "I have " << c1.GetCents() << " cents." << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

It's not clear to me how the expression

```
Cents(4)+6
```

in line

```
Cents c1 = Cents(4) + 6;
```

is evaluated.
Yeah I know that we're overloading operator "+" for operands of types Cents and int respectively.

As I understand Censt(4) is the constructor, right? So when

```
Cents operator+(const Cents &cCents, int nCents)
 {
 return Cents(cCents.m_nCents + nCents);
 }
```

is called does cCenst become a reference to Cents(4)?

From the line

```
return Cents(cCents.m_nCents + nCents);
```

one can deduce that cCenst is an object of type Censt since we access m_nCents via member selection operator "." But Censt(4) is a constructor and not a class object.

To me it doesn't seem to make sense for cCenst to be a reference to Cents(4) since they're not equivalent.

Comment: You should reduce the number of tags here and apply the c++ tag to your question (if this is c++ that is).

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with operator overloading. Why couldn't you pose it as it relates to some arbitrary function `void foo(const Cents&)` with the usage example being `foo(Cents(4))`?

Comment: Yeah I must admit that my example has little to do with operator overloading but rather it is about passing a class object to a function by reference. Yet I wouldn't edit the code and remove operator overloading stuff 'cause I cannot come up with an example that would make sense. But taking into account your wise remark I will change the question title.

Comment: @MaxGreen: Thanks; that's quite a lot better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand Censt(4) is the constructor, right?

No, not quite. You *never* call a constructor directly, even though this syntax makes it kind of seem like you do.

Here you're constructing a temporary of type `Censt` with constructor argument `4`.

Think of it more like this:

```
Censt x(4);  // creates a `Censt` with name `x` from argument `4`
Censt(4);    // creates a `Censt` with no name from argument `4`
```

It's *not* a function call.

> does cCenst become a reference to Cents(4)?

Yes.

> But Censt(4) is a constructor and not a class object.

Again, no. It *is* an object.

Comment: Now that you told me that Cents(4) creates an unnamed object I understand how function parameter "cCenst" can be a reference to it. Thanks)

Comment: To be more precise, `Cents(4)` is an expression that is an rvalue. Just as `4` is an rvalue.

Comment: @KubaOber: One level of abstraction up, it's an object. Two levels of abstraction down, it's a sequence of characters in a source code file. Being precise is great but context is everything.

Comment: I just thought that it's useful to bring the term into the discussion, as it's quite hard to talk about most of modern C++ without making the distinction. I'm not saying that somehow you erred greatly by not mentioning it :)

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand Censt(4) is the constructor, right?

`Cents(4)` is an expression which creates a `Cents` object (resulting in a call to the constructor). The result of evaluating the expression is the object thus created.

> So when [...] is called does cCenst become a reference to Cents(4)?

It becomes a reference to the object that was created when the `Cents(4)` subexpression was evaluated.

> From the line `return Cents(cCents.m_nCents + nCents);` one can deduce that cCenst is an object of type Censt since we access m_nCents via member selection operator "."

`cCents` is of type `const Cents &`, because that is how it is declared.

> But Censt(4) is a constructor and not a class object.

`Cents(4)` is an expression. It is not a constructor. To elaborate: it is an expression, which requires calling of a constructor to evaluate, and which results in a `Cents` object.

In the expression:

`Cents c1 = Cents(4) + 6;`

The sub-expressions are evaluated first (according to operator precedence etc). So, `Cents(4)` is evaluated and becomes a `Cents` object. The overall expression could then be considered to be:

`Cents c1 = <a-newly-created-Cents-object> + 6;`

The `<a-newly-created-Cents-object> + 6` part is evaluated by next, by calling the defined `+` operator. In that operator method, the `cCents` parameter becomes a reference to `<a-newly-created-Cents-object>`.

Answer (score 0):

the constructor will create the object so after you get an object and an int so it will take the object.
It's not exactly a reference it's a const reference so you don't need to created it before because the object can't be modified.

Comment: No, constructors don't "return" anything.

Comment: Yes you right it wasn't the word that I would write. I changed it.

Comment: Constructors don't "create the object", either. At least, not in entirety. They initialise data members. Memory allocation and other stuff is handled separately by the language. That's why this is _not_ "calling a constructor"; indeed, constructors do not even have names (12.1/1)!